# The different solution compare to the book solution?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, geometry, logarithmic-scale

On a book I found an integral with its solution I'm trying to solve it as well in Mathematica 13.2.0 but They are very different?!!!! If anyone can help it out!(integral : Sqrt[(3 x)/(x + 2 d)]  d/(x - d), x])

The book solution:

```
  d * F[x_] := 2 Sqrt[3] Log[Sqrt[x] + Sqrt[x + 2 d]] + Log[Sqrt[3 x] - Sqrt[x + 2 d]] - Log[Sqrt[3 x] + Sqrt[x + 2 d]];
```

The Mathematical(13.2.0) solution:

```
   -Sqrt[3] d  Log[1 - Sqrt[x]/Sqrt[2 d + x]] + Sqrt[3] d  Log[1 + Sqrt[x]/Sqrt[2 d + x]] + d  Log[1 - (d - x + Sqrt[x] Sqrt[2 d + x])/(Sqrt[3] d)] - d Log[1 + (d - x + Sqrt[x] Sqrt[2 d + x])/(Sqrt[3] d)]
```

This  is how I solved it.

```
Integrate[Sqrt[(3 x)/(x + 2 d)]  d/(x - d), x] // TrigToExp
```

I made the first part of solution simple in by hand:

```
     -Sqrt[3] d  Log[1 - Sqrt[x]/Sqrt[2 d + x]] + Sqrt[3] d  Log[1 + Sqrt[x]/Sqrt[2 d + x]] == -Sqrt[3] d  Log[Sqrt[2 d + x] - Sqrt[x]] + Sqrt[3] d  Log[Sqrt[2 d + x]+ Sqrt[x]]
```

Comment: What you are calculating is an indefinite integral, i.e., an **anti-derivative**. You can add any arbitrary constant (even a complex constant) to the anti-derivative and still have a valid anti-derivative of the original expression. To verify Mathematica's solution, just use `D[sol, x] == expr // Simplify`

Comment: yes, but how I can get the same?

Comment: Even I ploted them with the same value but they are not equal:
F[x_] := 
  2 Sqrt[3] Log[Sqrt[x] + Sqrt[x + 2 d]] + 
   Log[Sqrt[3 x] - Sqrt[x + 2 d]] - Log[Sqrt[3 x] + Sqrt[x + 2 d]];
G[x_] := 
  2 Sqrt[3]*d*ArcTanh[Sqrt[x]/Sqrt[2 d + x]] - 
   2 d*ArcCoth[(3 Sqrt[d])/(d - x + Sqrt[x] Sqrt[2 d + x])];
d = 1;
Plot[{F[x], G[x]}, {x, 0, 5}]

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

expr = Sqrt[(3 x)/(x + 2 d)] d/(x - d);

G[d_, x_] = Integrate[expr, x]

(* -(1/(Sqrt[3] Sqrt[x]))
 2 d Sqrt[x/(2 d + x)] Sqrt[
  2 d + x] (Sqrt[3] ArcTanh[(d - x + Sqrt[x] Sqrt[2 d + x])/(Sqrt[3] d)] + 
    3 Log[-Sqrt[x] + Sqrt[2 d + x]]) *)
```

Verifying that `G` is a valid anti-derivative

```
D[G[d, x], x] == expr // Simplify

(* True *)

F[d_, x_] := 
  2 Sqrt[3] Log[Sqrt[x] + Sqrt[x + 2 d]] + Log[Sqrt[3 x] - Sqrt[x + 2 d]] - 
   Log[Sqrt[3 x] + Sqrt[x + 2 d]];
```

Verifying that the product `d*F` is a valid anti-derivative

```
D[d*F[d, x], x] == expr // FullSimplify[#, {d > 0, x > 0}] &

(* True *)
```

The different anti-derivatives are not required to be equal, merely to only differ by an arbitrary constant (can be complex or even piecewise constant).

```
Manipulate[
 ReImPlot[
  Evaluate[{G[d, x], d*F[d, x]}],
  {x, 0, 5},
  ImageSize -> Medium],
 {{d, 1}, -5, 5, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]